# What were the McCallisters' professions?

Tags: plot-explanation, home-alone

In the movie *Home Alone* (1990), the McCallister family is followed on their planned trip to Paris and subsequent mistake of leaving one child behind.

The McCallister home and surrounding neighborhood are also the target of career burglars who have marked the home as the best one. This suggests that the McCallister family is very wealthy, but there other things that suggest this as well including:

- A large home in one of Chicago's most expensive suburbs (the real home is valued around $2.4 million in today's money).
- A vacation including extended family (15 people IIRC) to Paris, France.
- Chauffeur service (vans) to and from the airport.
- Fine clothes and jewelry (remember the scene of Kate offering cash, checks, and jewels for a plane ticket home).

However, it is never mentioned, even slightly in passing, what Peter and Kate McCallister's professions are. The only hint we get is that maybe Kate is a fashion designer due to the mannequins in the home.

Is there any official evidence of what their line of work was, perhaps in a companion novel, interviews with the cast, writers, or director?

Comment: It is simply immaterial to the story, so not mentioned.

Comment: The vacation was a gift from Kate's brother in law as I recall.

Comment: He’s a mobster. There are a lot of pages in the internet explaining the signs…

Comment: @Holger - fanfic is fun but I've seen nothing definitive.

Comment: Chauffeured vans really aren't all that expensive (at least in the States). One company I worked for would send a limo to the airport to pick people up & bring them to our office because it was actually cheaper than having them take a taxi...

Comment: This got covered two days ago: https://www.nytimes.com/2023/12/20/movies/home-alone-mccallisters-wealth.html and https://www.cnn.com/videos/business/2023/12/22/home-alone-mccallister-family-rich-mattingly-magic-wall-cprog-cnntm-vpx.cnn

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The mom is a fashion designer

> Back in the McCallister house, Kevin's mother Kate was in her bedroom, talking on the phone to her office while she packed a suitcase. With her dark wavy hair, black business suit, and glittering jewelry, she looked like a character from Dynasty. But then, she was a clothes designer and worked in the fashion business.
>
> <sub><sup>Home Alone - Official Novelisation</sup></sub>

The dad works in "an office". No further info is provided.

> In the middle of this, Kevin's father Peter stepped out of the bathroom. He was a handsome man. with short black hair. He'd just come home from the office, and was still wearing his business shirt and tie.

---

For the record, Kevin's parents didn't pay for the trip to Paris.

> "So as a Christmas present," Kate continued, "my husband's brother gave us a trip to Paris so we can all be together for the holidays. Anyway we're leaving for Paris in the morning..."

It's certainly plausible that the taxis and other travel expenses were also included.

Comment: His dad could have been a businessman? "[but the novelization, written by Todd Strasser, suggests that Kate is a fashion designer and Peter is a generic businessman](https://ew.com/home-alone-mccallister-family-rich-8418746)"

Comment: @AJ - Yeah, that comment (and one about him being a stock trader) are examples of [citogenesis](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/citogenesis.png). Endlessly repeated, but without substance.

Comment: @AJ - The novelisation says what it says. There's no '*suggestion'* he does anything other than work in an office and wears a suit. He could be a lawyer or a stockbroker or anything senior enough to justify going on occasional business trips.

Comment: The trip may have been paid for, but the house is a mansion.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger - One does not need a large income to own a large house. It could have been a gift or an inheritance

Comment: Taxes alone make it expensive

Comment: @JasonPSallinger - Those would all be paid for in the ticket price :-)

Comment: @Valorum Incorrect.  You pay property tax and homeowners insurance in perpetuity, regardless of whether the house is paid for.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger - I was referring to the airplane tickets. That being said, you're not wrong. The simple upkeep of a house that large would run to tens of thousands of dollars a year or more, but if the house was owned outright, that wouldn't typically be more than the same cost as paying rent on a smaller property.

Comment: Of note, a _lot_ of people have houses significantly larger (more expensive) that would be logical based on their income because that's what "everyone" in America wants. Of course, they're in debt up to their eyeballs and really can't afford the payments, but they scrape by because you've got to keep up with the Jones'...

Comment: @FreeMan - That seems to be a constant theme. They're comfortable, but not well off. Small financial shocks like the $122 pizza or Kevin's $1000 hotel room-service bill tend to throw them for a loop

Comment: @Valorum: I wouldn't consider a $1000 room service bill to be a "small" financial shock, especially back in the '90s when the dollar was worth roughly twice what it is today. My last significant family vacation ran around $5000, adding $2000 present day to that would be a serious change in the financial planning that could affect anyone below the straight-up "wealthy" threshold. I consider myself well-off, and could absolutely handle it, but I'd still be quite shocked by it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - A financial shock is defined as something that causes you to lose a significant proportion of your income. A thousand dollars is a big chunk of change, but it's only going to be about weekly combined income of a fashion designer and a businessman.

Comment: That they don't have a nanny to circumvent this whole plot tells us that they're cash poor. A house worth half that could easily run upwards of 10k a month in services and utilities and on top of that there's the 100k a year in property taxes and insurance. "This year, the owners of 671 Lincoln Ave. in Winnetka, Illinois, will pay $50,066 in property taxes"